# Error installing gcc-devel on macOS Sonoma

Tags: macos, terminal, macports, sonoma, gcc

I am facing installing gcc-devel on my MacBook macOS Sonoma with macport. I am getting following error messages:

```
Continue? [Y/n]: Y
Portfile changed since last build; discarding previous state.
--->  Fetching archive for libgcc-devel
--->  Attempting to fetch libgcc-devel-14-20231001_1+stdlib_flag.darwin_23.x86_64.tbz2 from https://packages.macports.org/libgcc-devel
--->  Attempting to fetch libgcc-devel-14-20231001_1+stdlib_flag.darwin_23.x86_64.tbz2 from http://jog.id.packages.macports.org/macports/packages/libgcc-devel
--->  Attempting to fetch libgcc-devel-14-20231001_1+stdlib_flag.darwin_23.x86_64.tbz2 from https://nue.de.packages.macports.org/libgcc-devel
--->  Fetching distfiles for libgcc-devel
--->  Verifying checksums for libgcc-devel
--->  Extracting libgcc-devel
--->  Applying patches to libgcc-devel
--->  Configuring libgcc-devel
--->  Building libgcc-devel                              
Error: Failed to build libgcc-devel: command execution failed
Error: See /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_macports_release_tarballs_ports_lang_gcc-devel/libgcc-devel/main.log for details.
Error: Follow https://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets if you believe there
is a bug.
Error: Processing of port gcc-devel failed
ramchand@Rams-MacBook-Pro ~ %
```

Comment: And what does it say in the log file you were referred to?

Comment: Another question... do you really need the snapshot version of `gcc`?  You can't just install `gcc13`?  It looks like [`gcc-devel`](https://ports.macports.org/port/gcc-devel/details/) is broken on all architectures right now.